# Java ConcurrentHashMap multi-thead env

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I am making code that will be used like cache in multi-thread env.(If there is value already computed, I will not recompute it) So, I wondering below code is thread-safe.

```
public static <K, V> V getCreate(ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> map, K key, Function<K, V> function) {
    V v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
        return map.putIfAbsent(key, function.apply(key));
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```

I knew about computeIfAbsent but after read this question([Why ConcurrentHashMap::putIfAbsent is faster than ConcurrentHashMap::computeIfAbsent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081456/why-concurrenthashmapputifabsent-is-faster-than-concurrenthashmapcomputeifab/40086093)) and benchmark in my local env, I am finding other way. This is core logic of my benchmarking. getOrCreate faster about 9 times.

| Benchmark | Mode | Cnt | Score | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| computeIfAbsent | avgt | 2 | 3790.730 | ns/op |
| getCreate | avgt | 2 | 436.348 | ns/op |

```
@Benchmark
public void getCreate() {
    List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(i -> getCreate(concurrent2, i, function))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Benchmark
public void computeIfAbsent() {
    List<String> collect = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(i -> concurrent1.computeIfAbsent(i, function))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static final Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
static private final Function<Integer, String> function = i -> i.toString() + "!@!@!@";
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrent1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrent2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static <K, V> V getOrCreate(ConcurrentMap<K, V> map, K key, Function<K, V> function) {
    V v = map.get(key);
    if (v == null) {
        map.put(key, function.apply(key));
        return map.get(key);
    } else {
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheal. Google [Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) implement all what you need.

Comment: In your benchmark getOrCreate() you use put(), not putIfAbsent(). Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Since the data will not be changed if not in abnormal case, so putIfAbsent is right use case for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is thread-safe, but there is a possibility that the function will be called multiple times for the same value.

For example this race condition:

```
//thread 1
V v = map.get(key);
if (v == null) {

    // thread 2 comes in
    {
      V v = map.get(key);
      if (v == null) {
         return map.putIfAbsent(key, function.apply(key));
      } else {
          return v;
      }
    }

    // thread 1 continues
    return map.putIfAbsent(key, function.apply(key));
} else {
    return v;
}
```

In this case, both thread1 and thread2 will execute `function.apply(key)`, but the `putIfAbsent` will make sure only the first value is used. If you use `put` instead of `putIfAbsent` with this race condition, the last value will be used.

If you use `computeIfAbsent` with this race condition, only the first value will be used, but `function.apply(key)` will not even be executed the second time.

BTW, your benchmark is not really representative.

- You allways use different keys, so the case where the same key is used is not tested.
- The benchmark is single-threaded as far as I can see, so all locks will be skipped.

Comment: Sry for not including, benchmarks's information. This is configuration I used. Anyway I need change benchmark code in more representative. Thanks a lot. :)
@Threads(16)
@Warmup(iterations = 2)
@Measurement(iterations = 2)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on your data.**

PutIfAbsent is faster in general, but if most of the keys you try to access are present, ComputeIfAbsent might be faster because it avoids creating the objects, whereas PutIfAbsent always creates the objects.

You should really benchmark two cases: one in which the actual key is always present, and one in which the actual key is always absent.